# Fetching multiple itemlist using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

The below code is used to fetch item list from order_details

**Output expected multiple items**
[image]

Below code works fine for 1 ITEM but the 2nd item/multiple items are not fetched using the below regex.

I want it to be dynamic so that it should work for any number of the item found in the matching pattern.

```js
 var order_details = "Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n     Triple Insomnio Especial   S/37 1  S/37.90  Insomnio Especial  S/21 2 S/23.12 *Tipo de papa:*  - Papa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n     *Adicional :*  - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n     *Agrega Bebida:*  - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n     *Salsas:*  - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji S/0.00\n      "     ;
    
    var rx = /\s+(.*?)\s+(S\/.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(S\/.*?)\s+([\s\S]*)/
    
    var m = rx.exec(order_details)
    
    var Detalle = m[1]
    var Unidad = m[2]
    var Cantidad = m[3]
    var Total = m[4]
    var Other = m[5]
    
    console.log(Detalle)
    console.log(Unidad)
    console.log(Cantidad)
    console.log(Total)
    console.log(Other)
```

Comment: your string is not proper, new lines should be for each row right? why did new line came at "Insomnio Especial  \nS/212" ?

Comment: string comes  from the web so I have no control over it that's why I have to write a regex which will work for the case, even if we remove \n from Insomnio Especial \nS/212 the above regex doesnt work @TilakPutta

Comment: regex wont work if we remove \n .. but you can split once by \n and then by \t to get it as rows and columns

Comment: can you post exact string that is generated by web

Comment: exact string I have posted @TilakPutta

Comment: regex wont work if we remove \n .. but you can split once by \n and then by \t to get it as rows and columns 
Can you post answer according to this @TilakPutta

Comment: Tell me from where i can get that string, i will help you

Comment: Edited my order_details string please check now @TilakPutta

Comment: expected output?

Comment: The output image @The Scientist Method

Comment: @art check updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one,

```
(?:\s+?).+?\s+(S\/\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(S\/\d+\.\d+)
```

[try demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LVnJvM/2)

Comment: output id different as expected only 2 items should have been fetched , like in the output image @The Scientific Method

Comment: @art check it now, it is fetching two rows only.